# Move The New Record Entry Row In Access Table To The Beginning Row

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

Is it possible to move the "New Record Row" in an Access table to the beginning of the table?

For example, say you have 200 items entered into your table, you would have to scroll the whole way down to the bottom of the table to enter a new record.

Instead, your entry row would be in the first row of your table.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the table itself. Access adds new records to the bottom of the table by default as they are just containers to hold data. Forms are typically used to enter data.

To add records directly to the table, you can click the `New Record` button on the navigation bar at the bottom of the table window. This takes you directly to the new row to enter data.

[image]

Alternately, you could create a simple form to add new records.

Comment: Thanks! Agreed that a form should be used to enter the new data rather than the table itself.

Comment: I have someone who got into the habit of entering data via the table and hates using a form, I don't know why but I thought I'd ask if there was an option to accomodate this person.

Comment: Understood. You may want to remind them they risk data integrity by being in the table editing records like that. It makes it very easy to make mistakes by editing existing data by accident.